# Watin multithreading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, watin

I have a problem in my application, written in c# using WatiN.
The application creates few threads,and each thread open browser and the same page.  
The page consist of HTML select element:
 [image: example of select element]
 and a submit button.

The browsers should select a specific option and click on the submit button **at the same time** but instead they do it **"one by one"**.
Here is the **main** code lines:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads;i++ )
    {
        var t = new Thread(() => RealStart(urls[i]));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
}

private static void RealStart(string url)
    {
        using (var firstBrowser = new IE())
        {                
            firstBrowser.GoTo(url);
            firstBrowser.BringToFront();           
            OptionCollection options = firstBrowser.SelectList("Select").Options;
            options[1].Select();
            firstBrowser.Button(Find.ByName("Button")).Click();
            firstBrowser.Close();
        }
    }
```

What is the cause of the "one by one" selection instead of simultaneously selection?

Comment: I think that part of the framework uses locks... haven't checked though.

Comment: Is it possible to bypass or cancel the lock? @Kabbalah

Comment: No. Because locks are used to make code threadsafe. By removing them you wouldn't be able to call Button.Click in multiple threads.

Again, I haven't actually checked whether the framework uses locks. But this is most likely the case.

Comment: Have you tried with MTA instead?

Comment: @user7236293 When the Apartment State is set to MTA i'm getting the following error: "The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer."

Comment: Then I'm thinking the component you are using (IE) is thread-unsafe because it requires STA, so you're out of luck.

Comment: @user7236293 Yeah,its correct. "Since Internet Explorer is not Thread safe we need to use STA."(from WatiN's documentation). Do you have an idea how can I get over it?

Comment: Use something else than WatiN? Sorry this is really not my area of knowledge so I don't quite see another solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
After a long research I gave up using WatiN for this porpuse.
Instead, I have created HttpWebRequest and post it to the specific URL.
Works Like a charm:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/page.aspx");
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "username=user";
postData += "&password=pass";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
   stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I send those requests simultaneously, by creating a Thread for each request.